# Cyclomatic complexity issues with Simple Spring boot Rest Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, design-patterns, sonarqube

I am using SonaQube scans for my Java project and trying to understand cyclomatic complexity issues. However this is very know design issues, I am trying to understand why simple return statements causing issues.

```
public class HelloController{ 
   @GetMapping("/hello")
   public ResponseEntity<String> helloGet(){
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello");}
  }
}
```

The SonaQube report produces produces Cyclomatic Complexity 1 in HelloController.java

I did small change by moving body constructions to Service layer

```
public class HelloController{
  @Service
  HelloService service;
 
  @GetMapping("/hello")
  public ResponseEntity<String> helloGet(){
     String body = service.getResponse();
     return ResponseEntity.ok(body);}
  }
}

@Service
public class HelloService {
  public String getResponse(){
      retrun "Hello"
  }
}
```

After above change SonaQube report produces 2 cyclomatic complexity issues one is in Controller class and one in Service Class. I am wondering even though we don't have any conditional logic or any other logic, why simple retrun causing cyclomatic problems.
I appreciate all your thoughts.

Comment: If it complains about a cyclomatic complexity of 1, then I would say you have misconfigured the ruleset used in SonarQube.

Comment: Thanks for update. Is there any way to stop scanning for Cyclomatic Complexity and Cognitive Complexity.
I am using "Jacoco-maven-plugin" and "Sonar-maven-plugin" to export analysis. We can skip some classes or file from reports. Similarly is there a way to skip "Complexity" checks.  I am using "mvn clean verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=$$$" command to do analysis

Comment: In my Sonar Rules I haven't found any rule with that parameters. I checked from SonaQube tool. How can check

Comment: Cyclomatic complexity of 1 is the lowest possible. It is definitely NOT an issue. It would be an issue when greater 20.